# Connecting to store with mapStateToProps()

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I get the error/warning "Failed prop type: The prop `logged` is marked as required in `App`, but its value is `undefined` in App". I am unable to figure out why it is not getting the values from the store.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Provider, connect} from 'react-redux';
import store from './store/store';

import Signup from './components/Signup';
import Home from './components/Home';

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            logged: this.props.logged
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup}/>                        
                        <Route exact path="/home" component={Home}/>                            
                        <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
                            this.state.logged ?
                                <Redirect to="/home" push/> : <Redirect to="/signup" push/>
                        )}/>
                        <Redirect to="/"/>
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </Provider>
        );

    }
}

App.propTypes = {
    logged: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};


const stateToProps = (state) => ({
    logged: state.loggedUserState.logged
});

connect(stateToProps)(App);

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**loggedUserReducer.js**

```
const initialState = {
    pending: true,
    logged: false
};

const loggedUserReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    if (action.type === 'GET_LOGGED_USER') {
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            pending: false
        });
    }

    return state;
};

export default loggedUserReducer;
```

**store.js**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import loggedUserReducer from '../reducers/loggedUserReducer';

const reducers = combineReducers({
    loggedUserState: loggedUserReducer
});

const store = createStore(reducers);

export default store;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code

```js
//- Everything else..

connect(stateToProps)(App); //- Assign App here!

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

You forgot to assign App to the `connect`ed App you just initialized.

Do This instead.

```js
//- Everything else ... 

App.propTypes = {
    logged: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};


const stateToProps = (state) => ({
    logged: state.loggedUserState.logged
});

const ConnectedApp = connect(stateToProps)(App);

ReactDOM.render(<ConnectedApp/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Decorators!**

If you have decorators [enabled](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-decorators) you could also do.

```js
@connect(state => ({
  logged: state.loggedUserState.logged
})
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            logged: this.props.logged
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup}/>                        
                        <Route exact path="/home" component={Home}/>                            
                        <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
                            this.state.logged ?
                                <Redirect to="/home" push/> : <Redirect to="/signup" push/>
                        )}/>
                        <Redirect to="/"/>
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </Provider>
        );

    }
}

App.propTypes = {
  logged: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

More about decorators see: [this article](https://medium.com/google-developers/exploring-es7-decorators-76ecb65fb841)

More about react/redux see [this](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md)

**Warning about decorators** from @markerikson in the comments section below.

> Using decorators and proptypes like that will still result in a
>   warning. That's because you're assigning the proptypes to the wrapper
>   component generated by connect, while the data returned from mapState
>   is given as props to the wrapped component. This is one of the reasons
>   why we advise against using connect as a decorator.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I appreciate that, Thank you.

Comment: Conceptually, it makes sense ... it still gives ESLint error "'App' is a class  no-class-assign". I'm working through it.

Comment: Sorry about that, here is a more explained answer.

Comment: Note that using decorators and proptypes like that will still result in a warning.  That's because you're assigning the proptypes to the _wrapper component_ generated by `connect`, while the data returned from `mapState` is given as props to the _wrapped_ component.  This is one of the reasons why we advise against using `connect` as a decorator.

Comment: @KayaToast Looks like this question is solved, right? Don't forget to mark to accept the answer if you feel it answered your question.

Comment: @markerikson Thanks, I will add that up to the answer.
**PS**: I also never really use decorators but I know it as an option and thought I shouold add it for simplicity.